# Memcheck my Qt5 app: Killed

Tags: qt, qt5, valgrind

I'm trying to memcheck my Qt5 app with valgrind's memcheck.

The app has a QWebView and when it starts after some seconds it gets Killed by the OS (the terminal just says "Killed").
If run without valgrind, it works okay...

What happens?
Thanks.

Comment: How do you start you app under valgrind? What is the valgrind output?

Comment: Either by hand or by clicking the analyze button in qtcreator... It just says after some seconds "Killed" (after some lines that reports some error in qwebkit)